# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DateTime dtEndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    appToDate, 
    timeFormats, 
    null, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);

appToDate = 21-02-2013 12:30 AM

string[] timeFormats = { 
    "dd-MM-yyyy H:m tt", 
    "dd-MM-yyyy H:mm tt", 
    "dd-MM-yyyy HH:m tt", 
    "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm tt" 
};
```

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: and what are your timeformats?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the problem is your use of `H` combined with `tt`. `H` and `HH` indicate an hour in the range 0-23, where 12 is noon, and therefore PM.

I suspect you want `h` and `hh` instead of `H`... although you shouldn't need every combination of `h`/`H`/`m`/`mm`. (Do you *really* expect to see "1:5 PM"?) I suspect just `"dd-MM-yyyy H:mm tt"` should cover you.